# Converting string to bytes and send() it

Tags: c++, command-line-interface

I'm making a packet sender.

Where the user can input the packet they want to send on a RichTextBox.

```
this->packetdata = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox());
```

Sample input:

```
03 00 00 13 0e e0 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 03
00 00 6a 02 f0 80 7f 65 82 00 5e 04 01 01 04 01 01 01 01 ff
```

The server should receive:

```
03 00 00 13 0e e0 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 03
00 00 6a 02 f0 80 7f 65 82 00 5e 04 01 01 04 01 01 01 01 ff
```

But the server is receiving this instead:

```
30 33 20 30 30 20 30 30 20 31 33 20 30 65 20 65   03 00 00 13 0e e
30 20 30 30 20 30 30 20 30 30 20 30 30 20 30 30   0 00 00 00 00 00
20 30 31 20 30 30 20 30 38 20 30 30 20 30 30 20    01 00 08 00 00 
30 30 20 30 30 20 30 30 20 30 33 0a 30 30 20 30   00 00 00 03.00 0
30 20 36 61 20 30 32 20 66 30 20 38 30 20 37 66   0 6a 02 f0 80 7f
20 36 35 20 38 32 20 30 30 20 35 65 20 30 34 20    65 82 00 5e 04 
30 31 20 30 31 20 30 34 20 30 31 20 30 31 20 30   01 01 04 01 01 0
31 20 30 31 20 66 66 20                           1 01 ff
```

How do I convert the data on the `RichTextBox` to remove all space and treat each as byte and send it.

This kind of approach works though:

```
char this[] = {0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x13, 0x0e, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03
0x00, 0x00, 0x6a, 0x02, 0xf0, 0x80, 0x7f, 0x65, 0x82, 0x00, 0x5e, 0x04, 0x01, 0x01, 0x04, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0xff}
```

With that code, the server receives the correct data.

So how do I turn the Text inside the TextBox into something like that?

---

This works

```
int mysendfunc(char *sendbuf, int size);

(...)

std::string inputpkt = marshal_as<std::string>(this->packetdata->Text);
std::istringstream reader(inputpkt);
std::vector<char> pkt;
do
{
    // read as many numbers as possible.
    for (int number; reader >> std::hex >> number;) {
        pkt.push_back(number);
    }
    // consume and discard token from stream.
    if (reader.fail())
    {
        reader.clear();
        std::string token;
        reader >> token;
    }
}
while (!reader.eof());

int hehe = mysendfunc(pkt.data(), pkt.size());
```

Comment: Not being up on CLI, I can't answer if the have a magic function to do this, I suppose they do, but in standard C++ I would `istringstream` the input string, then slurp out formatted data using `operator >>()`, pushing each value into a `std::vector<uint8_t>` and finally send `vec.size()` bytes from `vec.data()`

Comment: @WhozCraig This could work can I see some example code? :)

Comment: You're treating the data as decimal, but it's actually hex.

Comment: @BenVoigt can you please point out where I'm treating it as decimal and how I should treat it as hex?

Comment: @zikdaljin: It's `reader >> number` that assumes decimal.  As I already said in my answer, you can use `reader >> hex >> number` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function using `istringstream` is really close.  To interpret the data as hexadecimal, you will need `reader >> hex >> number`.

And then

```
mysendfunc(&pkt[0], pkt.size())
```

---

Or use

```
array<String^>^ hexCodes = this->packetdata->Text->Split(" ");
Converter<String^, SByte>^ parser = gcnew Converter<String^, SByte>(&SByte::Parse);
array<SByte>^ bytes = Array::ConvertAll(hexCodes, parser);
pin_ptr<char> pkt = &bytes[0];
int x = mysendfunc(pkt, bytes->Length);
```

Comment: I got some error on `Array::ConvertAll` and on the split part.

Comment: @zikdaljin: Splitting the code up like this, what line is the error now?

Comment: the last line `pkt` now says `cli::pin_ptr<unsigned char> is incompatible with parameter of type char*`

Comment: @zikdaljin: Ok, it's a `signed char` vs `unsigned char` issue.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Actually now it gives error on `&bytes[0]` signed char vs unsigned char on that one now. and `Text->Split()` gives error too. `no instance of over loaded function`.

Comment: @zikdaljin: Did you change the lines above to `SByte`?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the ASCII codes for the *text* "03 00 00   ....". You actually want to send the string "030000...", in its serialized mode.

```
std::string str("03 00 00 13 0e e0 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 03
00 00 6a 02 f0 80 7f 65 82 00 5e 04 01 01 04 01 01 01 01 ff");
sendbytes(str.c_str(), str.size());
```